# Where are my files after TortoiseGit push?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

On my AWS instance I created an empty git repo. From TortoiseGit on XP, I pushed to the server and all seemed to go well. But there is no indication on the server that anything has happened - nothing new in git status or git log.

Where are the files I thought I pushed?

If I need to do a pull from the server instead of a push to it, what do I use as the URL of my Windows box?

Comment: This appears to work fine using the git shell. So it is some issue with TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem on my setup: TortoiseGit 1.5.8.0, git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0, but I found the solution. In my case the “Git Command Progress” window does not appear until… I kill git.exe process . When killed, push succeeds.

Comment: Thanks. That works for me too, but I have to do that every time? Is that a known TortoiseGit bug?

Comment: More info about this bug: http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=593

Answer (score 0):

I don't use TortoiseGit but, you should register remote repository url first using 'git remote' command. Then you can use its alias instead of url like 'git push  master'.

Answer (score -1):

Why would there be files on the server? It only ever stores objects. The files themselves are contained in blobs.

Comment: I assumed that after I pushed to the server, I would be able to checkout the files from the repo on the server. I also assumed that git log and git status would reveal some evidence that the repository on the server had been changed in some way by pushing to it from TortoiseGit. Are you saying this is not the case or just taking exception to my imprecise use of the word files?